# Recuperar el key de un diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios

La idea no es transformar el diccionario a una lista y de ahi recuperar el key.
Tengo este c'odigo de ejemplo sencillo para que se entienda el problema:

```
def usokey(inventario):
# aca, necesito recupear el key del diccionario.
    print('CLAVE DEL DICCIONARIO: ', inventario)
    if inventario.  == 10:  # que metodo uso para recuperar el key y comparar?
        print('ENCONTRO POR KEY')

def cargaLista():
    lista = []
    precio = float(input('INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL ARTICULO. \n'))
    lista.append(precio)
    cantidad = int(input(('INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE ARTICULOS. \n')))
    lista.append(cantidad)
    return lista


def cargarArticulos(inventario):
    codigo = int(input('CODIGO DE ARTICULO. \n'))
    while codigo !=0:
        tipo = (input('TIPO DE ARTICULO. \n')).upper()
        talle = input('TALLE DEL ARTICULO. \n').upper()
        contable = cargaLista()
        inventario['codigo']:codigo = tipo, talle, contable
        codigo = int(input('CODIGO DE ARTICULO. \n'))

inventario = {}
cargarArticulos(inventario)
usokey(inventario)
```

El c'odigo es el 10, el KEY y a,b,[10.10, 10] es el value del diccionario.
No s'e con qu'e metodo recupero el key?
Use diccionario.key() y no funciona.

La salida:

```
CODIGO DE ARTICULO. 
10
TIPO DE ARTICULO.
a
TALLE DEL ARTICULO.
b
INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL ARTICULO.
10
INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE ARTICULOS.
10
CODIGO DE ARTICULO.
0
CLAVE DEL DICCIONARIO:  {'codigo': ('A', 'B', [10.0, 10])}
```

Salutis.

Comment: Es recuperar el valor por medio de la clave, por ejemplo, '1': 'valor correspondiente'... donde '1' sería el valor de la clave y se busca recuperar el valor correspondiente a esa clave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es corregir la línea `inventario['codigo']:codigo = tipo, talle, contable` por `inventario[codigo] = tipo, talle, contable`, como te dijeron en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/594570/265345).

La mejor manera de comprobar que una llave está disponible en un diccionario es usando `in`.
Hay otras formas de conseguirlo como:

```
try:
    inventario[key]
    key_correcta = True
except KeyError:
    key_correcta = False
```

El problema de

```
if key in inventario.keys()
```

es que hace la búsqueda en tiempo lineal: `O(n)`.
Esto es despreciar la estructura hash del diccionario.
La palabra reservada `in` llama al método [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).
En el caso de un diccionario, este método se ejecuta de media en tiempo constante `O(1)`.
Por tanto es preferible escribir

```
if key in inventario
```

Probablemente la mejora del rendimiento no será apreciable, pero conviene escribir código de forma canónica.

Comment: Tal como dices. esa es la equivocaci[on.  Use algo que me sirvio y segui avanzando en esa linea y luego se me complico.  Luego entend[i el error.  Muchas gracias, por tu respuesta.

Comment: inventario.get(key) is not None no siempre funciona bien. Si el valor de la clave key es None, el condicional dará False a pesar de que la clave de hecho si existe en el diccionario. Yo en lo personal uso esa forma solo cuando estoy seguro de que ningún valor va a ser None.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

En la función `cargarArticulos()` tienes la siguiente línea:

```
inventario['codigo']:codigo = tipo, talle, contable
```

Esta sintaxis no es válida, `:codigo` no debe ir ahí, de hecho no se toma en cuenta, y lo que haces es crear una llave tipo `string` con el texto `codigo`, pero lo que necesitas es crear una llave con el valor de la variable `codigo`, de esta forma:

```
inventario[codigo] = tipo, talle, contable
```

Por otra parte, para poder ver si algún valor existe dentro de las llaves del inventario, podemos utilizar `if 10 in inventario.keys():` adentro de la función `usokey(inventario)`

Ejemplo completo:

```
def usokey(inventario):
# aca, necesito recupear el key del diccionario.
    print('CLAVE DEL DICCIONARIO: ', inventario)
    if 10 in inventario.keys():
        print('ENCONTRO POR KEY')

def cargaLista():
    lista = []
    precio = float(input('INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL ARTICULO. \n'))
    lista.append(precio)
    cantidad = int(input(('INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE ARTICULOS. \n')))
    lista.append(cantidad)
    return lista


def cargarArticulos(inventario):
    codigo = int(input('CODIGO DE ARTICULO. \n'))
    while codigo !=0:
        tipo = input('TIPO DE ARTICULO. \n').upper()
        talle = input('TALLE DEL ARTICULO. \n').upper()
        contable = cargaLista()
        inventario[codigo] = tipo, talle, contable
        codigo = int(input('CODIGO DE ARTICULO. \n'))

inventario = {}
cargarArticulos(inventario)
usokey(inventario)
```

Ejemplo del funcionamiento:

```
CODIGO DE ARTICULO. 
 10
TIPO DE ARTICULO. 
 a
TALLE DEL ARTICULO. 
 b
INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL ARTICULO. 
 10
INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE ARTICULOS. 
 10
CODIGO DE ARTICULO. 
 0
CLAVE DEL DICCIONARIO:  {10: ('A', 'B', [10.0, 10])}
ENCONTRO POR KEY
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Luego de mucho lidiar me d'i cuenta del error en m'i c;odigo y lo segui arrastrando a este ejemplo.  S'i, es correcto lo que dices, y es lo que deb'ia corregir.  La definici'on del diccio est'a mal.  Referido a t'u respuesta, tampoco es lo que busco y creo que sigue estando mal la definici'on.  Nuevamente, gracias. Take Care.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Buen día @Maury, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) En caso de que no resuelva tu problema por favor agrega información adicional para proporcionar una mejor solución.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato ¿Por qué propones `if 10 in inventario.keys():` en vez de `if 10 in inventario:`?

Comment: @JorgeLuis, no hay razón en particular jaja pero en cuanto a optimización del código `if 10 in inventario:` sería más rápido.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato. La rta. fue aceptada.  Creo que defino mal el dicionario.  Porque uso dic[xx] = algo. entonces asigno a ese indice y me condiciona para el resto.  Gracias, por la respuesta porque me permiti'o darme cuenta de la equivocaci'on.

Answer (score 0):

me parece que el metodo que buscas es `.get()`:

```
if inventario.get(10) is not None: 
    print("ENCONTRO POR KEY")
```

Ahora bien, solo como nota, si la idea es asegurar que exista la llave en el diccionario para no generar un error, puede que no sea necesario hacer esta comparacion, pues el mismo metodo impide que suceda, Esto es por que regresea un valor None cuando se inserta una llave inexistente en el diccionario.

```
my_dc = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
foo = my_dc.get('a')
type(foo) # int
bar = my_dc.get('c')
type(bar) # NoneType
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Comment: @pytonista_entusiasta.  Gracias por tu inter'es.  Lo comentado.  Creo que comet'i un error al definir el diccionario.  Si uso el metodo get() tal cual lo defin'i no me sirve tampoco.  Deber'ia definirlo como dicci = {'key1':'val1', key2:val2} y usando el get, quedar[ia dicio.get('key1'}... Ok. Muchas gracias, por la respuesta. Keep moving.

Comment: Y que pasa si el valor de la clave key es None?